# 3 monitors and 2 video cards problem with ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I`m totally new to ubuntu. My pc settings (hardware):
2 video cards (GTX 650) with sli
3 monitors + 1 tv connections.

I have installed the ubuntu 12.04 and after the install the left and right and tv screens where working. After long search on the web I found how to install the nvidia drivers and when I tried to control the screens and disable the tv, I got an error message: can`t save the configuration file ....

Search the web did find a solution that worked on my pc.
At the moment I disconnected the other 3 monitors (left, right, tv) so I could see in the middle monitor.

I refuse to believe that windows can do it and handle thus 3 monitores + tv and ubuntu (linux) can`t.

I tried to find a solution for this on line but failed.

Any help on how to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the nightmare that is Ubuntu with multiple Video cards.

I have been waiting for six years for Linux/Ubuntu to sort this out, and I will most likely have to wait another six years to see any results.

I have a similar setup at work. 3x Nvidia 640 GT cards, six 23" screens.
As a rule, one screen per GPU if you run SLI.

Without SLI, you can create a single x screen for each monitor and use Xinerama to combine them in one big screen.

Be warned, this breaks xrandr and compiz. It also breaks unity, so I would suggest using LXDE or openbox.

I have tried everything to get better results, but no luck.

My steps after clean install:
Use the additional drivers to install latest tested NVidia drivers (you could install latest drivers from the NVidia site, but that's usually a pain)

Use the Nvidia X server settings to do the following:
Configure each monitor as a separate x display
Enable Xinerama (it is OK to cry a bit at this part)
Set up the layout of your monitors
Save the settings to your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file
DO NOT APPLY SETTINGS - restart

If you are lucky, you will boot without problems, and have all your monitors working.

If not, you will log in and no icons or panels will load.

use Ctrl+alt+F1 to get a terminal
stop the display manager (lightdm, gdm or kdm)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

after install restart or start the display manager again

At the login screen - choose the lxde desktop session.

Comment: I re-installed ubuntu and reconnected the screens. I still getting the error message but now it works, I can disable or enable or move the order of the screens and it will take affects. I can`t explain it how I did it or why.
I didn`t know that in ubuntu you need 1 video card for 1 screen in order to work with SLI. not very good thing, if we look at windows it can have multiple screens on one video card and work with SLI. I am not much interested in running SLI on ubuntu but have the ability to change the screens configuration and save it.
Any thoughts on how to fix the error?
Thanks

Comment: I have found that the Nvidia settings does not always ask you to authenticate before you save the settings (it seems you need root access to edit the xorg.conf file.
You could try to launch Nvidia settings from the terminal:
    sudo nvidia-settings